# Low voltage/low power on 2 out of 4 LEDs newly installed

Tags: electrical, led, dimmer-switch, voltage

PROJECT - Recently replaced two ceiling light fixtures with (4) Easy-Up 6 in. Deep Baffle Color Selectable Canless LED Recessed Kit, made by Commercial Electric. Also installed new switches; lights operated by two 3-way switches, one Lutron Diva dimmer and one standard.

PROBLEM - When either 3-way switch is flipped, the two recessed lights on the left come on extremely weak and flicker, regardless of dim level. The two recessed lights on right work fine, no problems. Also, if you flip either 3-way switch off/on quickly the weak lights (on left) flicker bright one time, then come on fine. If lights are turned off for more than 10 seconds, then problem is back. Turning off/on in under 10 seconds all 4 lights work fine.

[image]

Is it possible the LEDs are bad, maybe dimmer is bad or not compatible? Or should I go back and recheck every wire connection? Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: There have been many problems with incompatible dimmers. Try removing the dimmer from the circuit and see how the lights function.

Comment: What are the blue wires doing?  What is the function of the yellow wires?

Comment: Was worried about. I’ll try removing the dimmer, thanks.

Comment: Yellow is my white wire and blue is ground, didn’t have a green pen color, sorry for the confusion. Blue (ground) in diagram is grounded to junction box between the two sets of LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot follow your sketch. First take pictures for later reference. I will take a guess and have you try a few things. First to eliminate the dimmer problem if there is one, turn the power off short the 3 dimmer wires together effectively removing it from the circuit. Turn on the power and see if they are all bright. Cycle the switches, all combinations. If you have problems other then if the flickering ones keep flickering the switches are OK.

If they are all bright you have a dimmer problem. If not swap the bulbs putting the good in the bad sockets and the bad in the good sockets. Did the problem follow the lamps, if so replace with new. Turn the power off and remove the dimmer short then turn the power on. It should work ok.

If not you have a wiring problem in the fixture.  At this point you have either solved your problem or know what it is. When you fix it and get all the lights bright do not forget to remove the dimmer short.

If this does not resolve the problem post some pictures and links to the switches and lights that give technical information not azon which is generally just sales info.